# How to check user must change password at next logon flag via Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have been  doing to report all user accounts that have the user must change password at next logon flag set, My question is : how do I set as `user must change password at next logon` instead of `1/1/1601 2:00:00 AM` in CSV output ?

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed", "Title", "manager", "department", "employeeid"  | Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}},"Title",@{n=”Manager Name”;e={(Get-ADuser -identity $_.Manager -properties displayname).DisplayName}},"Department","employeeid" | sort-object -property ExpiryDate | Export-Csv -Path "c:\export\expirydatenew.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated properties in select allow for real logic in their expressions, so you should be able to add

```
@{Name="User must change password";Expression={if($_.pwdLastSet -eq 0){"true"} else {"false"}}}
```

to your Select-Object

Also you need to add "pwdLastSet" to the properties you query with Get-ADUser

Comment: thanks for help I just want to set users who still has the box checked for "user must change password at next login" in active directory.

Comment: Sorry, thought the relevant attribute was "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed", on a quick check it appears to be pwdlastset. Fixed the answer.

Comment: even though the user is checked "user must change password at next login" flag script is returning as false. is there any logic issue?

Comment: No logic issue, but the property "pwdLastSet" needs to be pulled from the AD so it can be evaluated (see my edit to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

There is no logic issue!
Just as supplement... You can use either:

`pwdLastSet` with `($_.pwdLastSet -eq 0)` or

`PasswordLastSet` attribute with a `($_.PasswordLastSet -eq $null)` check.

Prior adding of either of two respectively to the queried properties with Get-ADUser is necessity.